# Text between lines using css

Tags: html, css

need help with text between lines using css. I have tried a code but it forces background color white on my page. I am looking for something like this. Thank you.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvqSn.jpg

Comment: Can you provide some code sample? May be using jsFiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7jGHS/

Comment: Much easier to make and use a background image, that would be an easy type of image to make.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/oh79df02/

Comment: thanks a lot. Really appreciate your help.@Dmitriy

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do something like this,

```
h2 {
  line-height: 50px; 
}

h2:before, h2:after {
  width:250px;
  height: 8px;
  line-height: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  content: " ";
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  vertical-align: text-top;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7jGHS/2168/